# Invalid geometry type after clipping

Tags: geometry, clip, contour

I have two files (.xyz) with point data from a terrain. I'd like to create contour lines of said terrain but in a smaller area (limited by a polygon). After importing the points in two layers, I merge them into one layer. Without any problems I'm now able to create contour lines using the contour plugin (version 2.0.8.).

But as mentioned before, I only want the contour lines in a specific area (also because of the file size). So I'm using the clipping tool provided by QGIS (vector-geoprocessing-clip) with the point layer as input and the polygon layer as overlay layer. That gives me a layer only with the points from that specific area. When I try to process the clipped layer I get the following error message:

> Warning: Invalid geometry type for contouring - must be point
> geometry.

[image]

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? I know that this problem didn't pop up with older versions, as i was able process the exact same data with the exact same procedure without any problems. I'm using the following version of QGIS:

[image]

I'm fully aware that there are multiple workarounds available such ase "select by location". But working with big data I find it easier to have the selected area directly saved into a file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a plugin instead of the internal tools?

Comment: To my knowledge it's not directly possible with the internal tools. I would need to rasterize the pointdata. Either way I don't think that the plugin is causing the problem, as I'm able to process the data before clipping.

Comment: If the geometry type of the clipped layer is not point, have you tried to find out what it is? Or if is contains empty geometries or other oddities?

Comment: @user30184 That might be the problem. The original layer is of type PointZ, the clipped layer has the geomtry MultiPointZ. Why is QGIS changing the geometry when clipping?

Comment: Developer knows, I don't. Explode MultiPointZ into PointZ layer and you should be able to continue.